# Why can't I use my Half-Adder in another circuit?

Tags: logic-gates, logisim

Screenshot of my half-adder working like it's supposed to:

[image: screenshot of my half-adder working like it's supposed to]

I've then saved this as a circuit to use within another circuit:

[image: SO WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING]

So why is this not working?

Comment: Less exclamation marks, more describing how you're running the simulation, please. Also how you've made sure you actually are using the component you've created.

Comment: 'undefined' signals are a good sign that you need to re-read the instructions for that particular tool around how to package or instantiate sub-circuits, or connect the behaviour to the symbol.

Comment: Read the Logisim documentation. If you can't control your keyboard I'm not going to give you the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: screenshot of SUM/CARRY LEDs]

Those are [LED components](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/docs/2.7/en/html/libs/io/led.html) in your subcircuit, not output pins! Meaning that in your main circuit, on the right, there is nothing to connect to.

You should instead place output [pin components](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/docs/2.1.0/libs/base/pin.html) in your subcircuit. When you do that, there should be an actual output in your main circuit that you can wire to.

Comment: Thanks Asu! Wowsers this has been a rough intro onto stack  finally got there in the end

Comment: @scarteramani111666 you're very welcome here, but a bit of textual etiquette definitely goes a long way – and so does showing you've done your own part of the work. In this case, as Asu (whose answer you should accept!) that you should first read upon things like subcomponents yourself before asking about them. Again - a warm welcome, and here's to many more good questions from you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think you ought to do something about the unused input pins: -

[image]

If you were building this on a breadboard, would you leave all those input pins floating?

Comment: How do I get rid of them?

Comment: I was literally given a picture of a “half-adder” and then told to download and recreate it on logisim (first time ever using it) and I have touched a bread board once in my life so no, I wouldn’t think anything because I know absolutely nothing :)

Comment: Use two input devices not multi input devices or connect unused inputs to an appropriate logic level. I know nothing about logisim so don't expect anything from me on that.

Comment: you picked logic gates with more than 2 inputs. there are unconnected blue dots on the back of your logic gates, so its output should be undefined (not sure why it doesn't display as such in your first screenshot, though, it might be a Logisim thing). pick your top AND gate as an example: it would output 1 if all its inputs are 1. some inputs are unconnected/floating. what should it do with those? hint: in real life, you can't assume floating to mean a logic 0. if you have access to an arduino, plotting analogRead for an unconnected pin can do interesting stuff :)

Comment: turns out it doesn't show as undefined because this isn't a problem in logisim actually - the issue is that the two components on the right are lights, not outputs for the subcircuit... going to post an answer.

Comment: @Asu unconnected input pins are a problem. The outputs may be what you say they are but, that contradicts what the OP said: "screenshot of my half-adder working like it's supposed to"